# Sendgrid reply to

Tags: sendgrid

I am using HelpScout and sending through SendGrid (in order to track opens, bounces etc). I am having issue because eBay, which sends member messages to our customer support HelpScout app, rejects our replies with messages such as:

```
bounces+544081-5160-me=example.org@sendgrid.info 
is not a registered email address...  
add to whitelist etc..
```

Here are some of the headers from a HelpScout reply sent through SendGrid. As you can see it has this `bounces...` email address everywhere.

```
Delivered-To: me@example.org
Return-Path: <bounces+544081-5160-me=example.org@sendgrid.info>
Received: from o1638913x156.outbound-mail.sendgrid.net (o1638913x156.outbound-mail.sendgrid.net. [163.89.13.156])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id ly8si1461978wjb.40.2015.05.19.16.22.21
        for <me@example.org>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Tue, 19 May 2015 16:22:22 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of bounces+544081-5160-me=example.org@sendgrid.info designates 163.89.13.156 as permitted sender) client-ip=163.89.13.156;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounces+544081-5160-me=example.org@sendgrid.info designates 163.89.13.156 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=bounces+544081-5160-me=example.org@sendgrid.info;
       dkim=pass header.i=@sendgrid.me
Received: by filter0448p1mdw1.sendgrid.net with SMTP id filter0448p1mdw1.14711.555BC5AB1
        2015-05-19 23:22:20.183545946 +0000 UTC
Received: from secure.helpscout.net (unknown [10.100.60.108])
  by ismtpd-019 (SG) with ESMTP id 14d6e7c27b3.1336.1b3f18
  for <me@example.org>; Tue, 19 May 2015 23:22:19 +0000 (UTC)
From: Customer Support <help@oursite.com>
To: me@example.org
Subject: Fwd: Your message to ebayuser123 was blocked, because it wasn't sent from your registered email address.
Message-Id: <reply-8673-92216597-234152896-1432077739-1043083945@helpscout.net>
```

Why is SendGrid creating this address and is there a way to prevent it - I need an address that doesn't change so that I can whitelist.